# How to update unique table row numbers before inserting new row at existing position

Tags: sql, postgresql

SQL table:

```
 id |  name
----+--------
  1 | apple
  2 | orange
  3 | apricot
```

The `id` is primary key, unique, could be `SERIES`. The goal is to insert new row where `id` equals 2 and shift existing row numbers below, that is 2 and 3, to 3 and 4 position.

I have tried shift rows before inserting new row:

```
"UPDATE some_table SET id = id + 1 WHERE id >= id"
```

but an error occurred:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "some_table_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(3) already exists.
```

Is there some effective way to do such an operation?

The table should look like this after update:

```
 id |  name
----+--------
  1 | apple
  2 | cherry
  3 | orange
  4 | apricot
```

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? The primary key value has no meaning whatsoever. Its **only** job is to be unique. It doesn't matter if a PK value is `1`, `42` or `47336497`. You should create a separate column to define a customized sort order

Comment: I'm creating the rule set for execution by order 1,2,... and I must have the ability to modify, delete or insert the row by specified number (1,2, etc.). Yes, I can do that by sorting, just trying to find the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I think the attempt is futile, you *can* achieve that by marking the primary key constraint as deferrable:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table
(
  id int, 
  name text
);

alter table some_table 
  add constraint pk_some_table 
  primary key (id) 
  deferrable initially immediate; --<< HERE
```

In that case the PK constraint is evaluated at per statement, not per row.

Online example: https://rextester.com/JSIV60771

Comment: Glad to know [these](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-set-constraints.html) PostgreSQL options, thanks indeed.

Answer (score 0):

update Names 
set id=id+1
 where id in
 (select id from Names where id>=2 order by id desc);

Here first you can update the id's and then you can insert

insert into Names (id,name) values(2,'cheery')

Comment: That results in the same error. The `order by` in the sub-query is completely meaningless for the `IN` operator.